# How to import/export a dashboard in Kibana using a RESTful API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I would like to use a HTTP method to post new dashboards to my local Kibana instance, but I couldn't find much documentation on using an API to do this.

There was a pull request on Kibana that mentioned it was adding this functionality, but there was limited documentation on how to use it:
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/10858

An example of a dashboard I'm trying to post:

`{
  "_id": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890op",
  "_type": "dashboard",
  "_source": {
    "title": "my-app",
    "hits": 0,
    "description": "",
    "panelsJSON": "",
    "optionsJSON": "{\"darkTheme\":false}",
    "uiStateJSON": "",
    "version": 1,
    "timeRestore": true,
    "timeTo": "now/d",
    "timeFrom": "now/d",
    "refreshInterval": {
      "display": "1 minute",
      "pause": false,
      "section": 2,
      "value": 60000
    },
    "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
      "searchSourceJSON": ""
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Export:

```
curl "localhost:5601/api/kibana/dashboards/export?dashboard=980381a0-a266-11e7-8f86-edd4a877426e" > export.json

{
  "version": "7.0.0-alpha1",
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890op",
      "type": "dashboard",
      "properties": {
        "title": "my-app",
        "hits": 0,
        "description": "",
        "panelsJSON": "",
        "optionsJSON": "{\"darkTheme\":false}",
        "uiStateJSON": "",
        "version": 1,
        "timeRestore": true,
        "timeTo": "now/d",
        "timeFrom": "now/d",
        "refreshInterval": {
          "display": "1 minute",
          "pause": false,
          "section": 2,
          "value": 60000
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Import:

POST the response from the dashboard export API.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" -d @export.json http://localhost:5601/api/kibana/dashboards/import
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler answer worked perfectly. 
I was trying to import dashboards from Java app to Kibana. Following worked fine on 6.3.0:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:5601/api/kibana/dashboards/import");
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(IMPORTED_JSON_STRING);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("kbn-xsrf", "true");
request.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: Hmm I thought dashboard API is only in 6.4+